# Load resque worker without rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, resque

The resque jobs I have do not depend on anything in Rails, but I'm having a hard time starting workers without the rails env. I've seen this post, but it didn't help ([ruby resque without loading rails environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898499/ruby-resque-without-loading-rails-environment))

Here is my current rake file:

```
require "resque/tasks"

task "resque:setup" do
  root_path = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../.."

  require "#{root_path}/app/workers/myworker.rb"
end

#task "resque:setup" => :environment
```

The commented task would load the Rails env and everything works, but that's not what I want. When running `rake resque:work` I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
No such file to load -- application_controller

Tasks: TOP => resque:work => resque:preload
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've only added a lib/tasks/resque.rake file and haven't modified your Rakefile, you'll still be loading your Rails environment when you call rake resque:work.  Try this for Rakefile:

```
unless ENV['RESQUE_WORKER'] == 'true'
  require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
  My::Application.load_tasks 
else
  ROOT_PATH = File.expand_path("..", __FILE__)
  load File.join(ROOT_PATH, 'lib/tasks/resque.rake')
end
```

And then this for your resque.rake file:

```
require "resque/tasks"

task "resque:setup" do
  raise "Please set your RESQUE_WORKER variable to true" unless ENV['RESQUE_WORKER'] == "true"
  root_path = "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/../.."
  require "#{root_path}/app/workers/myworker.rb"
end
```

Then call `rake resque:work RESQUE_WORKER=true`

Answer (score -2):

I referred the link [here](https://gist.github.com/snatchev/1316470) It worked perfectly for me:

This error was resolved, by running

```
$> QUEUE=* rake environment resque:work
```

a cleaner solution was to define a rake task:

```
task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] ||= '*'
  #for redistogo on heroku http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611747/rails-resque-workers-fail-with-pgerror-server-closed-the-connection-unexpectedl
  Resque.before_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }
end
```

and now

```
rake resque:work
```

Worked perfectly

Thanks.

Comment: This ensures that the Rails environment _is_ loaded. The OP asked about running it _without_ rails.